# How to write to a second column in excel in C

Tags: c, excel

So now that I figured out how to write to an excel file (Thank you guys so much for that!), I'm wondering if there is a way to write to a second column in excel. I'm actually sending two different variables to this excel file and I'd like them side-by-side as opposed to right next to each other. I didn't see any other questions asking this for the C language, so thought I'd throw it out that. If there is one, feel free to link me the question and I apologize for wasting the space!

```
File * fp;
fp = fopen("C:\\Documents and Settings\\MyName\\Desktop\\Filename.csv", "w");
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("Couldn't open file\n");
    return;
}
for (j = 0; j<Variable0; j++){
fprintf(fp, "%f\n", (j+Variable1);
fprintf(fp, "%f\n", (j+Variable2);
}
```

Comment: It depends how you're _sending_ your data to Excel now. Can you provide a snippet of your code to access the Excel file.

Comment: If you tell us which of the various technologies you are using to write to an excel file and show us some code example, then you probably will get an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not writing an Excel file, you are writing a comma-separated value file (CSV). It can however, still be opened with Excel. There is a huge difference. ***Each column is separated with a comma.*** Each row is seperated by a newline character.

```
File * fp;
fp = fopen("C:\\Documents and Settings\\MyName\\Desktop\\Filename.csv", "w");
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("Couldn't open file\n");
    return;
}

float otherVar1 = 1.0f; // random thing you want to put in second column
float otherVar2 = 2.0f; // random thing you want to put in second column

for (j = 0; j<Variable0; j++){
    fprintf(fp, "%f,%f\n", (j+Variable1), (otherVar1));
    fprintf(fp, "%f,%f\n", (j+Variable2), (otherVar2));
}
```

Make sure you remember to close the file as well!

```
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Ahh, I apologize for not being aware of how much of a difference it made. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer whenever you see fit. Glad I could help.

Comment: I will definitely accept. My only question is the (otherVar1) and (otherVar2) additions you made. What exactly are those? I apologize for being so ignorant with my C knowledge.

Comment: @TZPike05 That is just a random variable I added. In my example, otherVar1 is a float that will be placed into the second column, first row. Please note that fprintf specifier changed too. `%f,%f` instead of `%f`. For each `%f` it accept one argument from the list. I highly recommend you read the format specifier section on this page. http://www.cplusplus.com/fprintf

Comment: @TZPike05 No problem. Like I wrote in the answer, please make sure you close the file!

Answer (score 0):

With a CSV file, Columns are separated by comma, and rows by enter.

Example:

```
Col1,Col2
Data1,Data2
```